# What is a viable alternative to getOne(long id) in Spring

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, option-type

I am writing an `update` method in Spring Service and it says the getOne() is deprecated, I have reviewed alternatives and the `findById(long id)` seems to be the go to option, but I am struggling to get this to work in my case.

I want to update the `name` field of an object saved in the database. I then want to resave it in the database with the updated name.

I initially had this code with the `getOne()`

```java
Society inDb = societyRepo.getOne(id);
inDb.setName(societyUpdate.getName());
societyRepo.save(inDb);
```

I have tried to amend this as follows,

```java
Optional<Society> soc = societyRepo.findById(id);
soc.ifPresent(society -> society.setName(society.getName()));
societyRepo.save(soc);
```

but as `soc` is now Optional I can't save it back in the database.

Is it acceptable to write another method in the SocietyRepo `Society findbyId(long id);` which will then allow me to use `Society s = societyRepo.findById(id); to get the` Society`from the database, update the`name` field and then resave in the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this all happens in a single transaction you actually don't need to call `save`.

If it isn't in a single transaction, or you want to keep the call to `save` for clarity, the following will work:

```java
societyRepo.findById(id)
    .ifPresent(society -> {
        society.setName(societyUpdate.getName());
        societyRepo.save(soc);
    });
```

Note: I changed `society.getName` to `societyUpdate.getName` assuming it was a typo on your side.

Comment: That's great thank you

Answer (score 3):

Things may have moved on.  According to https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/deprecated-list.html as of spring-data-jpa 3.0.0 ...

```
org.springframework...JpaRepository.getById(ID) use JpaRepository.getReferenceById(ID) instead.

org.springframework...JpaRepository.getOne(ID) use JpaRepository.getReferenceById(ID) instead.
```

So getReferenceById seems to be a driect replacement.